# Ruby, DI inside another class loop

Tags: ruby, loops, oop, dependency-injection

I met some obstacles when i tried to inject dependency inside this code, goal is to pass object to a function, injecting dependency. I've tried it with procs, but it doesn't make any sense since proc `parser = Proc.new { Parser.new }` called a new object, but arguments where passed after initializing, i didn't tried lambdas, and feel myself completely lost finding the way that doesn't violates Ruby style. Please, help me out.

Here's the code:

```
class Interface
  attr_reader :data, :parser

  def initialize(data = [1, 2, 3], parser = Parser.new)
    @data = data
    @parser = parser
  end

  def parse_fresh_reports
    data.each do |datum|
      parser.new(datum).run
    end
  end
end

class Parser
  attr_accessor :datum
  
  def initialize(datum)
    @datum = datum 
  end 
 
  def parse_report
    puts "from #{self.inspect} #{datum}"
  end
end

Interface.new.parse_fresh_reports
```

I want something like this

```
class Interface
  attr_accessor :data, :parser

  def initialize(data = [1, 2, 3], parser = Parser)
    @data = data
    @parser = parser
  end

  def parse_fresh_reports
    data.each do |datum|
      parser.run(datum)
    end
  end
end

class Parser
  attr_accessor :datum
  
  def self.run(datum)
    set_params(datum)
    parse_report
  end

  def set_params(datum)
    @datum = datum
  end

  def parse_report
    puts "from #{self.inspect} #{datum}"
  end
end

Interface.new.parse_fresh_reports
```

I don't know if it's ok to pass const as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parser = Parser.new` does not work because `Parser.new` requires an argument.

You can pass in a constant, it will pass the content of that constant. In this case the Parser class. It's a [Class object](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html). But how you've written the Parser class mixes class methods like `self.run` with instance methods like `set_params`. In order to make it work, you'd have to make everything a class method.

```
class Parser
  # Everything inside the following block affects the class Parser.
  # Not instances of Parser.
  class << self
    attr_accessor :datum
    
    def run(datum)
      set_params(datum)
      parse_report
    end

    def set_params(datum)
      @datum = datum
    end

    def parse_report
      puts "from #{self.inspect} #{datum}"
    end
  end
end
```

However, that means there can only be one thing parsing at a time.

---

Instead, pass in a new Parser object and *then* give it its data. It can be passed straight to `run`.

```
class Interface
  attr_reader :data, :parser

  def initialize(data = [1, 2, 3], parser = Parser.new)
    @data = data
    @parser = parser
  end

  def parse_fresh_reports
    data.each do |datum|
      # Pass the datum directly to each run.
      parser.run(datum)
    end
  end
end

class Parser
  def run(datum)
    puts "from #{inspect} #{datum}"
  end
end

Interface.new.parse_fresh_reports
```

This allows other parsers to be passed in.

```
class MyParser < Parser
  def run(*)
    super
    puts "Me, too!"
  end
end

Interface.new([1, 2, 3], MyParser.new).parse_fresh_reports
```